# Phoenix return 200 status code for POST

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

My Phoenix API returns `200` status code for POST request instead of `201`. Phoenix default uses `200` if I am not set the status code.

Here is sample response.

```
conn |> json(%{created_at: response[:timestamp], notes: response[:notes], data: data})
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can set the status code manually using `Plug.Conn.put_status/2`:

```
conn
|> put_status(:created)
|> json(%{created_at: response[:timestamp], notes: response[:notes], data: data})
```

Phoenix's `phoenix.gen.json` task does the same: https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/dd8ce7bd65bd8749e901349d5789bcb94a95521b/priv/templates/phoenix.gen.json/controller.ex#L17.

Comment: Is there any other way in Phoenix auto send `201` for POST requests.

Comment: No, Phoenix tends to be explicit, and this is an official way of changing status: https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/pull/1076/files